# Dimensional Analysis on Maximum speed of Sailboat

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dimensional-analysis

I'm doing the MIT Physics 1 : Classical Mechanics course, offered by OpenCourseware. I'm watching the first lecture and reviewing the slides, and don't seem to understand this question on Dimensional Analysis:

> *The speed of a sail-boat or other craft that does not 
>   plane is limited by the wave it makes – it can’t climb 
>   uphill over the front of the wave. What is the 
>   maximum speed you’d expect? 
>   Hint: relevant quantities might be the length l of the 
>   boat, the density ρ of the water, and the 
>   gravitational acceleration g.*

Here is a link to the question - [LINK](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-01sc-physics-i-classical-mechanics-fall-2010/introduction-to-mechanics/units-and-dimensional-analysis/MIT8_01SC_slides01.pdf)- It is on slide 15.

Any guidance to help solve this problem will be much appreciated!

Comment: A displacement boat creates a standing wave between it's bow and stern.  Try looking at what point the craft has to start climbing it's own wave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an equality with probable physical meaning, the dimension of both sides must be coincide. The velocity $v$ has dimension $L/T$. Similarly, length $l$ has $L$, density $\rho$ has $M/L^3$, acceleration $g$ has $\cdot L/T^2$. The equality implies

For length dimension,
$$1=x-3y+z$$
For mass dimension,
$$0=y$$
For time dimension,
$$-1=-2z$$
Thus a probable hypothesis is
$$v=C\sqrt{gl}$$

Answer (score 0):

On Google or Wikipedia look into something called the Froude number.

The question on the slide is asking how you to pick $x,y$, and $z$ so that the dimensions on both sides of the equation
$ v = l^x\rho ^yg^z$ 
match.

$[v] = L/T$
(i.e. speed has dimensions of length over time)

$[l] = L$

$[\rho] = M/L^3$

$[g] = L/T^2$

Let's just try multiplying the three quantities on the righthand side together and seeing what the units are. This is equivalent to setting x, y, and z to 1:

$[l\rho g] = L^2M/(L^3T^2) = M/(LT^2) $

That does not have the dimensions $L/T$ so that can't be the answer. Notice $\rho$ is the only quantity on the rhs with dimensions of mass. Speed doesn't have mass as a dimension, so $y$ must be $0$;the top speed of the boat is independent of the water density.

Let's try $x = 1, y =0, z = 1$

$[l^1\rho^0 g^1] = L^2/T^2 $

We're close. The answer must be $x = 1/2,  y =0, z = 1/2$.

There a more systematic approach as well. One can writes down a system of algebraic equations based on the exponents of each dimension on the two sides of the equation:

Mass:  $0 = y $

Length:  $1 = x + z$

Time:  $-1 = z^{-.5}$

Comment: In accordance with our [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714), I'm temporarily deleting this.